# Why is this dictionary turning into a tuple?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a complex dictionary:

```
l = {10: [{'a':1, 'T':'y'}, {'a':2, 'T':'n'}], 20: [{'a':3,'T':'n'}]}
```

When I'm trying to iterate over the dictionary I'm not getting a dictionary with a list for values that are a dictionary I'm getting a tuple like so:

```
for m in l.items():
    print(m)

(10, [{'a': 1, 'T': 'y'}, {'a': 2, 'T': 'n'}])
(20, [{'a': 3, 'T': 'n'}])
```

But when I just print l I get my original dictionary:

```
In [7]: l
Out[7]: {10: [{'a': 1, 'T': 'y'}, {'a': 2, 'T': 'n'}], 20: [{'a': 3, 'T': 'n'}]}
```

How do I iterate over the dictionary? I still need the keys and to process each dictionary in the value list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a dictionary you can add another variable while iterating over it.

```
for key, value in l.items():
    print(key,value)
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two questions here.  First, you ask why this is turned into a "tuple" - the answer to that question is because that is what the `.items()` method on dictionaries returns - a tuple of each key/value pair.

Knowing this, you can then decide how to use this information.  You can choose to expand the tuple into the two parts during iteration

```
for k, v in l.items():
    # Now k has the value of the key and v is the value
    # So you can either use the value directly
    print(v[0]);
    # or access using the key
    value = l[k];
    print(value[0]);
    # Both yield the same value
```

Answer (score 1):

I often rely on [pprint](https://pydoc-zh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/pprint.html) when processing a nested object to know at a glance what structure that I am dealing with.

```
from pprint import pprint
l = {10: [{'a':1, 'T':'y'}, {'a':2, 'T':'n'}], 20: [{'a':3,'T':'n'}]}
pprint(l, indent=4, width=40)
```

Output:

```
{   10: [   {'T': 'y', 'a': 1},
            {'T': 'n', 'a': 2}],
    20: [{'T': 'n', 'a': 3}]}
```

Others have already answered with implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I did discuss figure out how to process this. Here is the implementation I came up with:

```
for m in l.items():
    k,v = m
    print(f"key: {k}, val: {v}")
    for n in v:
        print(f"key: {n['a']}, val: {n['T']}")
```

Thanks for everyones help!